# How can I map longitude and latitude of events in a city?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, data-visualization

I have a big array with 50.000 objects containing the location of different kind of events in a city. I now need to map those data points **without** a map projection …

The array looks similar to this. Because it's all in one city the longitudes and latitudes are all very close to ea:

```
var nyc = 
    [{"city":"NYC","longitude":-73.935242,"latitude":40.730610},
    {"city":"NYC","longitude":-74.044502,"latitude":40.689247}]
```

For each data point I'm drawing a rect on the canvas but since the data points are so close to each other all my approaches resemble a unreadable cluster of rects. How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: what exactly do you want it to look like?

Comment: look into topojson, it will solve your problem of topography and data formats

Comment: @f.khantsis it should just look like a a regular map of the city but ofc only the elements in the array get drawn, so there are gaps but the city should still be recognisable since there are so many data points

Comment: Are you drawing them on a canvas of the world (-90 to 90 in latitude and -180 to 180 in longitude)? Can't you simply define the canvas with the bounding box of your city (i.e. zoom in)? Might be easier to help if you share some more code.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. You don't want too many markers per city, right? How about one marker per city with a click function for an infowindow with all events of that city? I guess markers, polygons and infowindows are the only options Google Maps offers you. But since I don't know what it should look like I can't make suggestions ;)